# Export list of all successful civimails?

Tags: civimail

I feel I should know this and the answer is going to be obvious. Is there a way to export a list of successful civimails? I need the mailing name and date, and it would help to have the mailing list sizes but this isn't crucial. I don't need the participants' details.

I'm using D6 and the latest Civi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CiviCRM inbuild reports (i.e Mailing Detail or Summary report) or [extended mailing stats](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-mailing-stats) extension. You can export the result as CSV or PDF

Comment: Better answer than mine!

Comment: I KNEW it was obvious! Thanks Pradeep. I'll also be testing the extnded mailing stats extension. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution, but as a one off you could list the mailings with Find Mailings, select a suitable number of rows per page, select all the table and copy and paste into Excel. I doesn't have the list size. To more than this I think you'd have to do a query of the database and write some code to also query the report to get the list size.

Comment: Clever workaround :-)
Thanks Mick.